# Variable Updates but Reverts Back to Old Value

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure my issue is with `var contact_id = this.id`, and the `#edit_contact_update` function.

The user clicks on the edit button for a contact, and then a module pops up. It loads the contact information correctly, and any changes save to MYSQL and updates the table correctly.

The issue is if you select another contact to update after you save the first. When you select the next contact the modal will pop up with the correct information, but when you go to save and it calls #edit_contact_update the contact_id never updates under this function. Its id is still under the previous contact and therefore updates the prior contact again, with the wrong information.

```
$('.edit-contact').click(function(e) {
    // Populate the Edit Contact Modal
    var contact_id = this.id;
    alert("Inital ID = " + contact_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: "controller/client-view/contact-modale-mysql.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {select_contact: contact_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response){

            var len = response.length;

            for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                var first_name = response[i]['first_name'];
                var last_name = response[i]['last_name'];
                var position = response[i]['position'];
                var phone_number = response[i]['phone_number'];
                var email = response[i]['email'];
                var pin = response[i]['pin'];
            }
            document.getElementById("edit_contact_name").value = first_name + " " + last_name;
            document.getElementById("edit_position").value = position;
            document.getElementById("edit_phone_number").value = phone_number;
            document.getElementById("edit_email").value = email;
            document.getElementById("edit_pin").value = pin;
            alert("Updated 2 ID = " + contact_id);

            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

    $('#edit_contact_update').click(function(e) {
      alert("Updated ID 3 = " + contact_id);

      // Saves any updates to the database
      var position = document.getElementById("edit_position").value;
        var phone_number = document.getElementById("edit_phone_number").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("edit_email").value;
        var pin = document.getElementById("edit_pin").value;
        alert("Updated ID 4 = " + contact_id);
      $.ajax({
        url: "controller/client-view/contact-modale-mysql.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {update_contact: contact_id, contact_position: position, phone_number: phone_number.replace(/\D/g,''), email: email, pin: pin},
        dataType: 'json'
        })
              alert("position-" + contact_id);
            // Update the contact on the contacts tab after uploading to the database
          document.getElementById("position-" + contact_id).innerHTML = position;
          document.getElementById("number-" + contact_id).innerHTML = phone_number;
          document.getElementById("email-" + contact_id).innerHTML = email;
          document.getElementById("pin-" + contact_id).innerHTML = pin;

    });
  });

<!-- .modal -->
<form id="clientContactEditForm" name="clientContactEditForm">
  <div class="modal fade" id="clientContactEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="clientContactEditModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- .modal-dialog -->
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <!-- .modal-content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- .modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h6 id="clientContactEditModalLabel" class="modal-title inline-editable">
            <span class="sr-only">Contact name</span> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="edit_contact_name" disabled=""  required="">
          </h6>
        </div><!-- /.modal-header -->
        <!-- .modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- .form-group -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="text" id="edit_position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position" required="" value="Position"> <label for="edit_position">Position</label>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
          <!-- .form-group -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="tel" id="edit_phone_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required="Phone Number" value=" "> <label for="edit_phone_number">Phone Number</label>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
          <!-- .form-group -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="email" id="edit_email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" value="E-mail"> <label for="edit_email">E-mail</label>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
          <!-- .form-group -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="text" id="edit_pin" class="form-control" placeholder="Pin" value="Pin"> <label for="edit_pin">Pin</label>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
        <!-- .modal-footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" id="edit_contact_update" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button> <button type="button" id="edit_contact_cancel" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div><!-- /.modal-footer -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
</form><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: What is that `for` loop?

Comment: When you attempt for the 2nd time to update, do `alert("Inital ID = " + contact_id);` have the new ID?

Comment: @Craftein yeah it updates with the correct id for `"Initial ID"` and ` " Updated 2 ID"`, but after I click the submit button and it calls `"#edit_contact_update"` it reverts back to the previous id.

Comment: Once you've submitted your 2nd attempt, how many times `alert("position-" + contact_id);` gets fired?

Comment: Just one time...

Comment: @DaveK. I've got this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tLnd938j/, if you noticed, it is firing 2x. Not sure what is happening with the 2nd ajax for the 2nd attempt. Have you checked your inspect -> network if that request is throwing an error? or any errors at all from the inspect -> console or network?

Comment: I've been getting this error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("position-" + contact_id).innerHTML = position')` but when I look at the code in the browser it's correct.

Comment: I've been using Safari, but just tried Chrome again too, and it's still only firing 1x on my end.

Comment: Code in the browser?
I want to confirm that these elements you are trying to populate, gets populated? `document.getElementById("pin-" + contact_id).innerHTML = pin;` When you look at them in the browser, it shows the changes?

Comment: the code in the browser, just clicking inspect element. The initial time those elements do properly populate.

Comment: I did just discover something interesting though... I removed `  and the other 5... With that removed, it continues like before populating the wrong id; however, it then comes back with a 2nd fire with the correct id.

Comment: All I'm doing here is guess. Not enough information, html etc are included.
Not sure what and where are `'position-' + [dynamic id/number]` if they are table and existing. Two things though, first is I would suggest passing the id from first ajax.success to the modal as well, and take it from there. Second is that, your `$('#edit_contact_update').click(function(e) {` makes another event listener n*(number of edit). The reason it only fire once it is because of that error, it terminates the script thus, only firing the first event listener registered in the DOM.